# Magento prod site clone not working like prod

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm seeing different output from my production clone site than on production.  The most obvious difference I can see so far (and there is probably more) is that the js/css references in the main document look to have been min-ified on production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/media/css_secure/eb0df35e22a81d2150af7faddb2a014c-v2.18.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/media/js/f081fea0e1f96e90201edfc964382601-v2.18.js"></script>
```

But in my production clone, they come back like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/responsive/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/amasty/amfpc/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/responsive/default/css/AutoComplete.css" media="all" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/prototype/prototype.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/lib/ccard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/prototype/validation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/scriptaculous/builder.min.js"></script>
...
```

There are 2 problems I see:

1. I would like my clone to have the same min-ified CSS and JS as prod
2. The CSS and JS urls for the clone start with "/git/magento" which is actually the name of my Magento ROOT folder on disk, so that's not right and they all come back as 404s.

When I did the production clone, I didn't bring over any of the files in `/media` (that's the advice I got).  Is there anything I should be doing differently?  I also followed these steps: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site

Why is the same code returning different CSS and JS references?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had to create the MAGENTO_ROOT/var and MAGENTO_ROOT/media folders and give them the correct permissions. This was very helpful: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after

I guess the problem was that the /media folder was not writable to the web server process, so it couldn't save the minified/cached version of the js/css.